# Linq update and merge two result sets (from data tables)

Tags: c#, linq

I have two tables:

```
Customer:                
+------------------------------+
|   ID        |    Address     |
|------------------------------|
|   1         | London, UK     |
|   2         | Paris, France  |
+------------------------------+

Updated Customer:                
+------------------------------+
|   ID        |    Address     |
|------------------------------|
|   1         | Birmingham, UK |
+------------------------------+
```

How do I merge the tables to get this result? :

```
Customer:                
+------------------------------+
|   ID        |    Address     |
|------------------------------|
|   1         | Birmingham, UK |
|   2         | Paris, France  |
+------------------------------+
```

C#/ Linq code I tried with union:

```
DataTable customer = new DataTable();
customer.Columns.Add("ID", typeof(int));
customer.Columns.Add("Address", typeof(string));

DataTable updatedCustomer = new DataTable();
updatedCustomer.Columns.Add("ID", typeof(int));
updatedCustomer.Columns.Add("Address", typeof(string));

customer.Rows.Add(1, "London, UK");
customer.Rows.Add(2, "Paris, France");

updatedCustomer.Rows.Add(1, "Birmingham, UK");

var cust = from row in customer.AsEnumerable()
select new
{
    ID = row[0],
    Address = row[1]
};

var uCust = from row in updatedCustomer.AsEnumerable()
select new
{
    ID = row[0],
    Address = row[1]
};

var updatedTable = cust.Union(uCust);
//Please use cust and uCust objects, not customer and UpdatedCustomer.
```

Union is giving me a table with all 3 rows, however.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var query=from c in customer.AsEnumerable()
         join uc in updatedCustomer.AsEnumerable()
         on c.Field<int>("ID") equals uc.Field<int>("ID") into lf
         from uc in lf.DefaultIfEmpty()
         select new
         {
             ID=c.Field<int>("ID"),
             Address=uc==null?c.Field<string>("Address"):uc.Field<string>("Address")
         };

//this will get the result you want,but it is not DataTable.
//you need to convert query to datatable .
DataTable result =customer.Clone();

query.ToList().ForEach(q=>result.Rows.Add(q.ID,q.Address));
```

Answer (score 3):

You can write your own comparer to just compare ID

```
public class IDComparer  : IEqualityComparer<DataRow> 
{   
    public bool Equals(DataRow x, DataRow y)
    {           
        return (int) x["ID"] == (int) y["ID"] ;
    }

    public int GetHashCode(DataRow obj)
    {                           
        return (int) obj["ID"] ;
    }               
}
```

then to use it,

```
var updatedTable = uCust.Union(cust, new IDComparer ())
```

Comment: Great solution, very slick

Answer (score 2):

Adding a primary key, and using Merge will get you your answer.

```
    DataTable customer = new DataTable();
    var customerIdColumn = new DataColumn("ID", typeof(int));
    customer.Columns.Add(customerIdColumn);
    customer.Columns.Add("Address", typeof(string));
    customer.PrimaryKey = new[] { customerIdColumn };

    DataTable updatedCustomer = new DataTable();
    var updatedCustomerIdColumn = new DataColumn("ID", typeof(int));
    updatedCustomer.Columns.Add(updatedCustomerIdColumn);
    updatedCustomer.Columns.Add("Address", typeof(string));
    updatedCustomer.PrimaryKey = new[] { updatedCustomerIdColumn };

    customer.Rows.Add(1, "London, UK");
    customer.Rows.Add(2, "Paris, France");

    updatedCustomer.Rows.Add(1, "Birmingham, UK");


    customer.Merge(updatedCustomer, false);
```

**EDIT**

To do this with linq you need a not in.  I've made this rather verbose for clarity.  You should be able to make the code more concise pretty easily however.

```
var cust = customer.AsEnumerable();
var uCust = updatedCustomer.AsEnumerable();

var newCust = (from c in cust join u in uCust on c.Field<int>("ID") equals u.Field<int>("ID") select u);
var newUCust =
    (from cu in cust where !(from ucu in uCust select ucu.Field<int>("ID")).Contains(cu.Field<int>("ID")) select cu);
var joined = newCust.Concat(newUCust);
```

Comment: is there a way to do this with linq instead? I have converted the datatable to enumerable down the line and have performed many linq operations on it so far.

Comment: @David Check my edited answer, that should work well for you.

Comment: I think use linq left join is ok

Comment: @Tim.Tang Yes, its a fine answer as well.  +1  I hope you reciprocate. :)

Comment: +1 for effort, though I liked the left join a bit more :P thanks

Comment: @David I like it a bit more too.  Though the compare answer that just came in from sgmoore is super slick.  Great idea